# How nginx to update reverse proxy its conf dynamically?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, scripting

I am planning to set a reverse proxy with nginx , my question is i want to dynamically change the reverse proxy in nginx  depends on the request is coming 
Let us say i  have request xyz request from a device i want it mapped to abc without manually editing the conf ,  I will be passing the zyz = abc through ftp to a file in nginx